# Drop table query of access not getting executed when running the installed exe

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a project developed in vb.net who's backend is access database. Every thing works fine when executed in visual studio but when I create a setup of this project and install it in windows 7, some how the drop table is not getting executed. To solve this I granted rights of "write" to the "database" folder where the access db file is located. I don't want the users to go there in the Programs Files and give the write access to the folder. Can this rights assigning task be automated? Can't we assigning write rights to the "database" folder while creating the setup itself? Is there any other solution to fix it?

Comment: data files should not be installed to `Program Files` that is what the various User and AppData folders are for

Comment: Ya actually i didn't wanted users to directly access this file so i have kept it there, neways i will try this out. Thanks!!!

Comment: look into isolated storage if you want to obfuscate where the file is, however if you have applied security to the Access DB, it shouldnt matter if they can find it.

Comment: I agree with what you have suggested but the AppData directory worked in my case, juss wanted a simple solution/alternative, thanks for it again. And yes i have applied security to the access DB but i am worried if the users moves or deletes it.